# What is the standard 2-generating set of the symmetric group good for?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, teaching

I apologize for this question which is obviously not research-level. I've been teaching to master students the standard generating sets of the symmetric and alternating groups and I wasn't able to give a simple, convincing example where it's useful to use the two-generating set $\{(1,2),(1,2,...,n)\}$. (I always find it annoying when we teach something and we're not able to convince the students that it's useful.) I asked a couple of colleagues and no simple answer came out -- let me stress that I'd like to find something simple enough, like a remark I could do in passing or an exercise that I could leave to the reader without cheating him/her. Do you know such examples ?

Comment: I never heard or thought of this as "the" standard generating subset, it's one among many. It's maybe just the simplest one on 2 generators we can describe in mathematical terms. (By the way it also works in the symmetric group over $\mathbf{Z}$, using the shift $+1$ as infinite cycle, generating the whole finite support symmetric group.) A little farther from teaching level: It's also known to be highly inefficient compared to "generic pairs", if one wants to get the size of the Cayley graph as small as possible, or if one wants to generate random elements by multiplying random generators.

Comment: It's a little unclear from the question whether you're most interested in the fact that these particular two elements generate $S_n$, or whether you care more about the observation that $S_n$ is $2$-generated in general.

Comment: I don't know what it's particularly useful for, but find this presentation interesting as a reminder that the Coxeter presentation by simple transpositions (which I like and use) is by no means minimal: to me the interesting part is that there's a generating set with just two elements

Comment: @YCor I called the set standard because it is the one that is found in all algebra textbooks for students. But I agree there are many 2-element generating sets: a theorem of Isaacs and Zieschang says that any nonidentity permutation can be completed to such a set.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins you're right. In fact I am not particularly interested in this 2-set, and I'd be pleased to bo told concrete applications of having a pair of generating elements in $S_n$.

Comment: It's not my question, but I'd be interested, even more generally than the significance of $\operatorname S_n$ being $2$-generated, in the significance of *any* group being $2$-generated.  For example, I seem to remember that most simple groups are $2$-generated.  Is that just a fact, or does it have any further implications?

Comment: @LSpice All finite simple groups are $2$-generated. In fact the probability of any two randomly chosen elements generating a nonabelian simple group $G$ tends to $1$ as $|G| \to \infty$.

Comment: It allows one to construct a covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is (a) ramified at only 3 points (b) has covering group $S_n$. This covering is defined over a number field. (A 2-generated group is a quotient of the free group with 2 generators which is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1-3 \mathrm{points}$. Is this example too advanced?

Comment: This might be a good question for [matheducators.se].

Comment: I must say that I thought the answer would have interest for educators, but interesting answers would come mainly from researchers.

Comment: This isn't really a mathematical answer, but the way I like to think about this presentation is that I have a set of plates on a "lazy Susan", one of those wooden turntables you can put plates on in the middle of a table. One generator is rotating the lazy Susan, and the other is swapping the two plates directly in front of me. Using only these two operations, I can get any ordering of the plates that I like.

Comment: The answer is: "Absolutely nothing. Uh ha haa ha."

Comment: (Apologies if this answer is duplicated somewhere else. It's certainly similar in spirit to some others, such as the beautiful answer about Galois theory, but is more elementary.) A generating set for a group $G$ is very good for determining if a homomorhims $H\to G$ is surjective, since you just need to check if the generators are in the image! One can set lots of easy exercises that are variants on this. This is similar to Derek Holt's answer, except that because Derek focussed on homomorphisms *from* $G$, one run into the awkward fact that most $S_n$'s are almost simple.

Comment: It can be used for building a cheap racetrack. A fast car can overtake a slower one only at a unique point in the track. (This is of course essentially the same answer as Robert Furber's.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of prime degree $p$, with exactly $2$ non-real roots.

You can view the Galois group of $f$ (i.e., the Galois group of the splitting $f$) as a subgroup of $S_p$. Complex conjugation shows that the Galois group contains a transposition. You can use Cauchy's theorem from group theory to show that the Galois group contains a $p$-cycle.

Then $f$ has Galois group $S_p$. This uses the slightly stronger fact that $S_p$ is generated by any transposition and $p$-cycle (which can be proved from the standard two-generating set).

In turn, constructing a polynomial with Galois group $S_5$ is useful for proving insolvability of the quintic.

Comment: But why is the order of the Galois group divisible by $p$?

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$. Then the splitting field of $f$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Since $f$ is irreducible, we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=p$. Then the degree of the splitting field is divisible by $p$, so the order of the Galois group is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Ah right, I was blind. This is nice indeed!

Comment: Marginally different presentation of the reasoning: the Galois group acts transitively on the $p$ roots since the polynomial is irreducible. So there’s an orbit of size $p$, the stabilizers have index $p$, Lagrange.

Comment: I believe that this result is usually credited to Richard Brauer.

Answer (score 22):

It might be interesting (to some) to see that every possible shuffle of a pack of $n$ cards can be achieved by a sequence of operations in which you either swap the first two cards or move the bottom card to the top of the pack.

Comment: Thanks! I knew this one. This is nice indeed, but I don't know if I would say it's useful.

Comment: @Matthieu Romagny perhaps rephrasing it as showing that the Bubblesort sorting algorithm works would convince you that this is useful? Although bubblesort is not particularly useful in practice as Obama noted: https://web.archive.org/web/20190907131624/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4yVlPqeZwo

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused I got curious, the actual remark on bubble sort is cut out into a short clip, on [Barack Obama - Computer Science Question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4RRi_ntQc8).

Answer (score 15):

As has been more or less said in comments, I think the important and useful thing to know is that $S_n$ can be generated by two elements.

It is less important which two you choose, but $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$ has the advantage that it is simply stated uniformly for all $n$.

Perhaps the single most important property of a generating set $X$ of a group $G$, and which could be explained to undergraduates, is that a homomorphism $f:G \to H$ to another group is determined by the images of $f$ on $X$. (This is the same principle as the fact that linear maps are determined by their images on a basis.)

So, if $H$ is a finite group, then there are at most $|H|^{|X|}$ homomorphisms from $G$ to $H$.  This is important in particular in both the complexity and practical aspects of algorithmic group theory, which is an active research area.

In fact it embarrassing to have to admit that, there is no known general algorithm for computing ${\rm Aut}(G)$ for finite groups $G$ that has better complexity than the naive method of testing all possible images of the elements in a generating set. (Of course that is not relevant to $G=S_n$, for which ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is known.)

(I should add that, to check whether a given map $X \to H$ really does extend to a homomorphism $G \to H$, you also need a set of defining relations on $X$. There are such sets known for the two "standard generators" of $S_n$ -see  [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eobrien/research/an-sn-present.pdf) for example - but they are less easily stated.)

Comment: The term "standard generators" is a term that appears in the computational group theory literature. It seems (as far as I can tell) this means generators that have nice properties and are used in implementations in GAP/Magma, e.g. for recognition algorithms for the group. Are $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,3,\ldots,n)$ "standard generators" in this sense?

Comment: @spin No, the "standard generators" in that sense are chosen individually for each group. The idea is that given a group $H$ that is either known or suspected to be isomorphic to the group $G$ in question, you can find the standard generators in $H$ as fast as possible by choosing random element of $H$. The standard generators of $S_n$ in that sense for $n \le 23$ can be found [here](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/alt/). After finding the standard generators, you can set up the isomorphism between $H$ and $G$ such that images and inverse images can be computed quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately the bound $|H|^{|X|}$ for $\text{Hom}(G,H)$ is quite crude so it is not clear to what extent the smallness of $X$ is a measure of the smallness of $G$. For example, let $G=S_n$ and $G'=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^r$. Choose $p>n$ prime and $r$ so that $p^r$ is comparable to (or even bigger than) $n!$, so $G$ and $G'$ have comparable sizes. (An example is when $p:=n+1$ is prime, then choose $r=n$.) In this case $\text{Hom}(G,S_n)$ will have size around $n!$ whereas $\text{Hom}(G',S_n)$ will be trivial.

Comment: Yes  I agree. The bound is useful for groups in general, but for symmetric groups it is usually too crude to be useful.

Comment: FWIW, (thinking of any "standard" generators in a computational context), in SageMath you can ask for the generators of a group in *three* ways: gens() gives the ones that were used in creating the group, gens_small() returns a set with "few" elements, and minimal_generating_set() really gives a minimal set. For SymmetricGroup(n), on my machine at least, all three agree on $(1,2),(1,2,\ldots,n)$ *except* for $n=3$, where the last function returns $(2,3),(1,2,3)$!

Answer (score 13):

It is good for understanding that a small number of generators does not mean a small group.

At your very earliest encounter with permutation groups, you might think that with two generators $\alpha$ and $\beta$, well, how much can you get? Especially if one or both of them are of small order? I mean, with $\alpha=(1,2)$ you just have $\alpha^2=\text{id}$, and $\beta=(1,2,\ldots,n)$ also gives you just $n$ different permutations $\beta^1,\ldots,\beta^n=\text{id}$ so "obviously" there cannot be much more, can there?

An obvious analogy is the dihedral group $D_n$, where from your two generators — a rotation, which gives you $n$ permutations, and a reflection that gives you two — you get $2n$ permutations. So you might expect not much more here — and you would be surprised.

(And a small afterthought, which is starting to wander off-topic: It may be instructive to note that the huge difference we see here between $D_n$ and $S_n$ does not arise from the number of generators, or from their orders, *nor from commutativity vs. noncommutativity*. Surely, for an abelian group one is not surprised that a small number of small-order generators gives you only a small number of group elements, because order of composing the generators does not matter. But $D_n$ and $S_n$ are *both* nonabelian beyond the very smallest cases, yet they behave very differently. — In fact, I'm not sure how best to characterize this difference, or whether there is a meaningful general phenomenon there, or whether it is just "that's the way these two groups are".)

Comment: In fact $S_n$ can be generated by an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$ for all $n>2$, but that's not obvious.

Comment: @Derek Holt - there are exceptions... $n=5,6,8$ Miller, G.A., On the groups generated by 2 operators, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 7, 14–32, 1901.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy Yes of course -  I should have remembered that!

Comment: @JPMcCarthy what happens for those $n$?

Comment: @David Roberts I do not know what goes wrong there exactly, sorry: https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-7/issue-10/On-the-groups-generated-by-two-operators/bams/1183416688.full

Comment: @JPMcCarthy I have asked a question on this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405477/low-order-symmetric-group-2-generation-n-5-6-8

Answer (score 11):

I've had occasions where I needed to know that some structure is "closed" under $S_n$.  It is very convenient to only check that it is closed under those two, specific permutations.  Afterwards, I can apply any permutation I want.

A similar idea is used to show that there is a finite axiomatization of NBG set theory.

Comment: Can you mention an example where it is easier to show closure under two permutations of different cycle types, rather than under several different permutations of the same cycle type?  In most situations that occur to me, if I can prove that a structure is preserved by $(1\ 2)$, then the same argument should prove that it's preserved by $(i\ i + 1)$ for all $i$, and hence by $\operatorname S_n$.

Comment: there are computational advantages of few generator - e.g. if you need to check that a large structure, e.g. a graph, is invariant under (often, induced) action of the group.

Comment: @LSpice Such situations occur quite often when you want some sort of closure under $S_n$, for all $n$ simultaneously, and at the same time you also want to express the situation finitely.  For instance, consider the following condition defined on unital rings: (#) "For any $n\in N$ and any $\sigma\in S_n$, if $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n=0$, then $x_{\sigma(1)} x_{\sigma(2)}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}=0$."  This can be checked much more simply via the condition (##) "If $x_1 x_2 x_3=0$, then $x_2 x_1 x_3=0$." It looks like we are only forcing closure under $(1\ 2)\in S_3$, but in unital rings (#)<=>(##).

Comment: Clearly (#)=>(##), so let's show the converse.  If $x_1 x_2 (x_3 \cdots x_n)=0$, then (##) implies $x_2 x_1 (x_3\cdots x_n)=0$.  So we have closure under $(1\ 2)\in S_n$.  Also, applying (##) to the product $x_1 (x_2\cdots x_n) 1=0$, we get $(x_2\cdots x_n)x_1 1=0$.  [This works even when $n=2$.]  So we get closure under the standard $n$-cycle.  If you see an easier way to make this argument work using $(i\ i+1)$, I'd be interested.

Comment: I should say that what motivates my question in the very first place is exactly the remark of LSpice. In most situations I encounter, after I've checked some property for $(1,2)$ then I notice that it works just the same for any transposition $(i,j)$ and hence for all permutations in $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is pushing the envelope in terms of "useful".

Given a finitely generated discrete group $\Gamma=\langle \gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k\rangle$, using the "Gelfand philosophy", its group algebra $\mathbb{C}\Gamma$ is the algebra of regular functions on its dual, $\widehat{\Gamma}$, and we write e.g. $\mathcal{O}(\widehat{\Gamma}):=\mathbb{C}\Gamma$.

If $\Gamma$ is generated by elements of finite order $n_1,\dots,n_k$, then, where $n=\sum_p n_p$, we have that $\widehat{\Gamma}$ is a quantum subgroup of the quantum permutation group $S_n^+$ as defined by Wang:

$$\widehat{\Gamma}\subseteq S_n^+.$$

It is long known that for finite $\Gamma$:
$$\widehat{\Gamma}\subseteq S_{|\Gamma|^2}^+,$$

and using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4007031/does-every-finite-group-g-have-a-set-of-generators-such-that-the-sum-of-the-or) we can show that in fact:
$$\widehat{\Gamma}\subseteq S_{|\Gamma|}^+.$$

The generators above show that we have:
$$\widehat{S_n}\subseteq S_{n+2}^+,$$

but as per the comments to [Jukka's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405273/35482), for $n\geq 9$ we have:
$$\widehat{S_n}\subseteq S_5^+.$$

Comment: This answer could equally apply to any generating pair including an element of order 2, right?

Comment: @YCor absolutely. Pushing the envelope in terms of useful but also pushing the envelope in terms of relevance.