# Low-order symmetric group 2-generation: n=5,6,8

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

In a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405256/what-is-the-standard-2-generating-set-of-the-symmetric-group-good-for#comment1038737_405273) at the recent question [What is the standard 2-generating set of the symmetric group good for?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405256/what-is-the-standard-2-generating-set-of-the-symmetric-group-good-for), it was remarked that the symmetric groups $S_n$ for $n\gt 2$, $n\neq 5,6,8$, can be generated by an element of order 2 and an element of order 3 (G. A. Miller, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **7** (1901), 424-426 doi:[10.1090/S0002-9904-1901-00826-9](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1901-00826-9)). The remaining three nonabelian cases can of course be generated by a pair of elements, but these are cycles of length $5,6,8$ respectively. What is the best that can be done in these cases, and is there a conceptual reason why these are exceptional? (eg the presence of the nontrivial outer automorphism of $S_6$? Or some action on an exceptional combinatorial object?)

---

**ADDED** By 'conceptual' proof I mean something more like 'structural', or the analogue of what in combinatorics is a 'bijective proof'. There should be some actual construction for the generic case that clearly breaks down for the small cases, due to a lack of space. Compare for instance the deep understanding of what goes wrong with the sort of handle moves that happen in high-dimensional topology, when we go down to dimension 4, and then why the replacement there will not work in lower dimensions. Simply counting two sets and noticing they have the same number of elements isn't the sort of thing I want. Nor do I want a proof that just writes down a pair of generators and checks they work, but of course I do want to see said generators.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? What do you want to minimize? The order of elements? You only want cycles (not double transpositions, etc)? That $S_5$ is not generated by a transposition and a 3-cycle is kind of obvious, I'm not sure what would be a "conceptual" argument.

Comment: By the way for every $n$ equal to $-1$ modulo $3$, $S_n$ can't be generated by an element of order 3 and a transposition. Because an element of order 3 fixes 2 elements, so these should be moved by the last one, but then the resulting group is cyclic of order $6$. Also it's clear that a transposition and an element of order 3 can't generate a transitive subgroup for any $n>6$. The 1901 Miller reference says that $S_n$ (for $n$ not $5,6,8$) can be generated by a pair of elements of order 2 and 3, but don't say a transposition.

Comment: @YCor aha, my mistake re transposition/order 2. I'll fix that. I'm not a group theorist, nor have I done much finite group theory since undergraduate days, so "kind of obvious" isn't obvious to me.

Comment: If you have given generators, you can draw a graph on the vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$ joining each element to its images. The group is transitive iff this graph is connected. For an element of order 3 you only draw triangles and leave fixed points. For a transposition, you only join two points. (Checking whether they generate is not as easy, but this transitivity condition is already an efficient obstruction).

Comment: Regarding the first question, I meant the order of elements, namely something of order 2 and something of order k smaller than n would be ideal.

Comment: I think one can quickly compute with GAP or something else those $n$ such that $S_k$ for $k=5,6,8$ is generated by an element of order 2 and an element of order $n$. (For $k=5$ we see without computation that $n=5$ works but not $n<5$.)

Comment: $S_5 = \langle x, y \rangle$ for some $x,y$ with $|x| = 2$ and $|y| = 4$; for example $x = (12)$ and $y = (1345)$. We have $S_6 = \langle x, y \rangle$ for some $x,y$ with $|x| = 2$ and $|y| = 5$, also for $|x| = 3$ and $|y| = 4$.

Comment: @YCor this is why I asked for a more conceptual reason, rather than just a computational one!

Comment: @spin why not add it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, but a  conceptual" reason for some fixed cases looks like asking a conceptual reason why $7\times 9=63$. Computation can help finding the right generating pair with some condition generalizing to larger $n$.

Comment: One quick way of seeing that $S_{5}$ is not $\{2,3\}$-generated is that, if it is,  the generator of order $2$ has to be an odd permutation, so a transposition. The element of order $3$ is a $3$-cycle: if it fixes the points interchanged by the transposition, then it commutes with the transposition. Otherwise, there is a point  fixed by both the transposition and the $3$-cycle. In either case, the two elements chosen generate a proper subgroup.

Comment: I don't think there needs to be a conceptual reason why some general rule has a few small exceptions - that happens all the time.

Comment: @Derek sure, but why *these* numbers, and not others?

Comment: @YCor, it's the difference between saying two groups are isomorphic because of some classification result for nonabelian groups of small order, or finding a specific permutation representation on some rich object. Here, I want to know what is the construction that gives the result for generic $n$ and why it fails for exactly these cases. And why not $n=7$? Is it something to do with small powers of primes below 7? With something like a small combinatorial design? What?

Comment: You would then probably have the answer if you have the proof of Miller's result.

Comment: I don't know what would be a good explanation. To see that $S_6$ is not $\{2,3\}$-generated, you can argue in similar lines as Geoff Robinson suggests. For $x,y \in S_6$ with $|x| = 2$ and $|y| = 3$ by considering the various possibilities for $x$ and $y$ you find that either $\langle x,y \rangle$ fixes a point, or it is imprimitive. For $S_8$ it is also possible for $|x| = 2$ and $|y| = 3$ that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is the $3$-transitive $PGL(2,7)$.

Comment: @YCor sure, but I don't like reading 1900-era group theory, and would prefer a clean, modern description making use of the advances of, I don't know, Emmy Noether in abstract algebra...

Comment: But checking that an explicit pair generates the symmetric group is not likely to use very advanced algebra, but rather combinatorics... just the language should differ a bit if explained now, compared to 120 years ago.

Comment: The proof by Miller is a direct calculation with permutations which works for degree $\geq 12$. His construction uses Bertrand's postulate. For degree $< 12$ he leaves the details to the reader and says they are easy to examine directly.

Comment: @spin Yes exactly, so for $n < 12$ there is no reason to expect anything other than random sporadic behaviour. Of course we can give proofs for all of the individual cases. IIRC, then for $A_n$, the examples examples that are not $\{2,3\}$-generated are $n=6,7,8$.

Comment: @YCor I didn't say "advanced algebra", but "abstract algebra". I mean, Miller didn't have access to things that we now take for granted, like the isomorphism theorems...

Comment: I don't think these sorts of problem tend to involve "abstract algebra."  To give a more modern example, see the paper [The Monster Group is Hurwitz Group](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~raw/pubs_files/MHurwitzweb.pdf) which shows that the Monster group is generated by an elt of order 2 and one of order 3 whose product has order 7.  It's just doing extensive calculations in a smart way.

Comment: Say $G$ is a group with $G = \langle x, y \rangle$ such that $|x| = 2$ and $|y| = 3$. If $|xy| = 2,3,4,5$ then $G \cong S_3,A_4,S_4,A_5$ respectively. Together with cyclic and dihedral groups these are the finite Von Dyck groups $D(r,s,t) = \langle a,b | a^r = b^s = (ab)^t = 1 \rangle$. By wishful thinking there could be some geometric explanation why $S_5$, $S_6$, and $S_8$ are not quotients of $D(2,3,t)$, but other $S_n$'s are. Or the question is really why are these not quotients of the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}) \cong C_2 * C_3$, but other symmetric groups are.

Comment: There are many comments, but I also agree with Derek Holt and others that there might not be any special reason, just that sporadic/random is expected in small cases. It is also unclear what a satisfactory answer would be. In his construction, Miller uses the fact that if $n \geq 8$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $n-2 > p > n/2$. And also that for such a prime $p$, a primitive subgroup of $S_n$ containing a $p$-cycle is $S_n$ or $A_n$.

Comment: @spin I don't disagree with the small case sporadicity, I just want to know precisely what determines the boundary, from a group theory point of view. You know, something like transitive actions and maximal subgroups and orbits and whatnot, not just a numerical criterion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is also possible to use the (exceptional) outer automorphism of order $2$ of $S_{6}$ to give an "explanation" of why $S_{6}$ is not $\{2,3\}$-generated, along the lines I used in comments for $S_{5}$ above. Take a $6$-cycle $\sigma \in S_{6}.$  Then $\sigma^{2}$ is a product of two disjoint three cycles  and $\sigma^{3}$ is a product of three disjoint $2$-cycles. These clearly commute. Now take an outer automorphism $\tau$ of $S_{6}$ which sends products of two disjoint three cycles to three cycles. Then $\tau$ must also send products of three disjoint transpositions to transpositions, since $\tau(\sigma^{2})$ and $\tau(\sigma^{3})$ must commute.

Now suppose that $S_{6}$ is $\{2,3\}$-generated say $S_{6} = \langle \alpha, \beta : \alpha^{2} = \beta^{3} = 1 \rangle.$ Then we may apply $\tau$ if necessary, and assume that $\beta$ is a $3$-cycle. Then $\alpha$ is an odd permutation, so is either a transposition, or a product of three disjoint transpositions.

In the former case, we have a contradiction since there is a point fixed by both $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In the latter case, none of the transpositions in $\alpha$ can fix all points moved by $\beta$, for otherwise that transposition would be central in $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle.$ It follows that $\alpha$ sends each point moved by $\beta$ to a point fixed by $\beta$ and conversely. It follows that $\beta$ and $\beta^{\alpha}$ commute. Now $\alpha$ normalizes the Abelian subgroup $\langle \beta, \beta^{\alpha}\rangle $, so that $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle   = \langle \alpha \rangle \langle \beta^{\alpha} ,\beta \rangle$  has order dividing $18$, a contradiction.

I do not know if there is an argument using the fact that $S_{8}$ is isomorphic to ${\rm GL}(4,2)\langle \gamma \rangle$, where $\gamma$ is the transpose inverse automorphism, to "explain" that $S_{8}$ is not $\{2,3\}$-generated.

Later edit: It would have been better perhaps to use the outer automorphism of $S_{6}$ to reduce to the case that $\alpha$ is a transposition,(in which case, generation requires that $\beta$ is a product of two disjoint $3$-cycles), and then note the general fact that when $n >1$, $S_{2n}$ is never generated by a transposition $\alpha$ and an element $\beta$ which
is a product of two disjoint $n$-cycles. For if it were, we may conjugate the pair and assume that $\alpha = (12).$ If either of the $n$-cycles in $\beta$ were disjoint from $\alpha$, then that $n$-cycle would be central in $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = S_{2n}$, a contradiction. Hence both $n$-cycles of $\beta$ contain a point moved by $\alpha$.

We may conjugate $\beta$ by a permutation fixing both $1$ and $2$ and assume that $\beta = (1357 \ldots 2n-1)(2468 \ldots 2n)$ without disturbing the generation property. Then $\langle \alpha, \alpha^{\beta}, \ldots, \alpha^{\beta^{n-1}}\rangle$ = $\langle (12),(34), \ldots , (2n-1 2n) \rangle$ is Abelian and normal in $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle = S_{2n},$ a contradiction.

Comment: Excellent, this is the sort of thing I was hoping for.

Comment: The argument I had in mind before: "It follows that $\alpha$ sends each point moved by $\beta$ to a point fixed by $\beta$ and conversely." => Hence $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$ is imprimitive, contradiction.

Comment: Say $S_8 = \langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$ with $|\alpha| = 2$ and $|\beta| = 3$. I think with similar arguments as in this answer, $\alpha$ must be a product of three disjoint transpositions, and $\beta$ must be a product of two disjoint $3$-cycles (else $\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle$ fixes a point or is imprimitive).  Then again with similar arguments wlog $\alpha = (12)(34)(56)$ and $\beta  = (178)(235)$. These permutations generate $PGL(2,7)$. Not sure what is a quick way to see they do not generate $S_8$ to finish the proof that $S_8$ is not $\{2,3\}$-generated.

Comment: I'm pretty skeptical that this is "more conceptual."  It's just saying that the outer automorphism lets you divide the number of cases by 2.  But I don't think doing 2 cases by hand is "more conceptual" than doing 4 cases by hand.

Comment: Here's something slightly easier for $S_6$. Notice that if $G$ is $(2,3)$-generated, $x^2=y^3=1$, then $\langle y,y^x\rangle$ generates a subgroup of index at most $2$ in $G$. Now $A_6$ cannot be generated by two conjugate elements of order $3$: by the outer automorphism, we can assume they are both $3$-cycles, but them it's clear.

Comment: Accepting this in the absence of any other further input. It seems like it's the best I'll get...

Answer (score 8):

Here is some data for generating pairs mentioned in a comment.

A group $G$ is $(r,s)$-generated if $G = \langle x, y \rangle$ with $|x| = r$ and $|y| = s$.

$S_5$ is $(2,4)$-generated, for example by $x = (12)$ and $y = (1345)$. And $S_5$ is not $(2,3)$-generated, although $A_5$ is.

$S_6$ is $(2,5)$-generated, for example by $x = (12)$ and $y = (13456)$. And $S_6$ is not $(2,s)$-generated for $s = 3,4$.

$S_8$ is $(2,4)$-generated, for example by $x = (12)(34)(56)$ and $y =(1564)(2837)$. And $S_8$ is not $(2,3)$-generated.

Comment: This pattern continues down: $S_4$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(134)$, and $S_3$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(13)$. We also have $S_8$ coming from $(12)$ and $(1345678)$, but something exceptional allows for the (2,4)-generation. And presumably something special happens for $S_7$, not sure what it is, to get (2,3)-generation.

Comment: Yes, in general $S_n$ is $(2,n-1)$-generated by $(12)$ and $(134 \cdots n)$. Also $(2,n)$-generated by $(12)$ and $(123 \cdots n)$.

Comment: Yes, the original question that inspired this one was about the second of these, which is why someone comment about (2,3)-generation. In some sense, $S_4$ and $S_3$ are exceptions to the exception, since the 'inefficient' generating cycle cannot be longer.